# SignalR reconnection with custom RetryPolicy does not respect that policy and adds additional delays

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr

I'm using the SignalR .NET client and server on .NET 6, and the reconnection delay does seem to work differently than I'd expect. I'm using the following code on the server to define a custom RetryPolicy:

```
connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .WithUrl(url)
  .WithAutomaticReconnect(new RetryPolicy())
  .Build();

public class RetryPolicy : IRetryPolicy
{
  public TimeSpan? NextRetryDelay(RetryContext retryContext)
  {

    var delay = retryContext.PreviousRetryCount switch
    {
      < 5 => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
      < 10 => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
      _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
    };
    Console.WriteLine($"NextRetryDelay count: {retryContext.PreviousRetryCount} elapsed: {retryContext.ElapsedTime} delay: {delay}");
    return delay;
  }
}
```

When I trigger a disconnect I get the following output from this:

```
NextRetryDelay count: 0 elapsed: 00:00:00 delay: 00:00:00
NextRetryDelay count: 1 elapsed: 00:00:08.1187903 delay: 00:00:00
NextRetryDelay count: 2 elapsed: 00:00:12.1619132 delay: 00:00:00
NextRetryDelay count: 3 elapsed: 00:00:16.2117377 delay: 00:00:00
NextRetryDelay count: 4 elapsed: 00:00:20.2883145 delay: 00:00:00
NextRetryDelay count: 5 elapsed: 00:00:24.3593463 delay: 00:00:05
NextRetryDelay count: 6 elapsed: 00:00:33.4387382 delay: 00:00:05
NextRetryDelay count: 7 elapsed: 00:00:42.4919265 delay: 00:00:05
NextRetryDelay count: 8 elapsed: 00:00:51.5778513 delay: 00:00:05
NextRetryDelay count: 9 elapsed: 00:01:00.6560698 delay: 00:00:05
NextRetryDelay count: 10 elapsed: 00:01:09.7329655 delay: 00:00:10
NextRetryDelay count: 11 elapsed: 00:01:23.7992479 delay: 00:00:10
NextRetryDelay count: 12 elapsed: 00:01:37.8539388 delay: 00:00:10
```

For every delay there seem to be roughly 4 seconds of an additional delay beyond the time I specific in this custom RetryPolicy. The second delay even has an additional 8 seconds, and these values seem pretty reproducible, though not perfectly so.

I adjusted the actual values for testing here, but my goal is to have a few very quick retries at the start. This does not seem possible with this ~8 second initial delay that comes out of nowhere.

Where do these additional delays come from, and how do I get .NET to respect the RetryPolicy I set here?

Comment: The extra time you are seeing is the `delay` you added + the time it took for the connection to fail. It seems like your SignalR reconnection is failing after 4 seconds of retrying, that's why it adds 4 (or 9/14) seconds instead of just your delay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you implement a custom IRetryPolicy, you have to take into account that the `delay` you put is added to the time the `HubConnectionBuilder` takes before trying to reconnect.

So, assuming your SignalR client is retrying for 4 seconds before returning that the reconnection was not possible, and adding the `delay` you set to that, you get the elapsed time you're getting.

4 seconds spent trying to reconnect + 5 seconds delay = 9 seconds added to the previous elapsed time.

Knowing that you can change your `delay` to fewer (or none) seconds to make the wait time faster.

I tried this behavior on a client that takes roughly 21 seconds to reconnect and added a 5 second delay, and got a steady 26 second wait time, so the RetryPolicy is working just fine.

```
NextRetryDelay count: 0 elapsed: 00:00:00 delay: 5
NextRetryDelay count: 1 elapsed: 00:00:26.1568207 delay: 5
NextRetryDelay count: 2 elapsed: 00:00:52.2934825 delay: 5
NextRetryDelay count: 3 elapsed: 00:01:18.3989711 delay: 5
NextRetryDelay count: 4 elapsed: 00:01:44.5205752 delay: 5
NextRetryDelay count: 5 elapsed: 00:02:10.6291636 delay: 5
NextRetryDelay count: 6 elapsed: 00:02:36.7462710 delay: 5
NextRetryDelay count: 7 elapsed: 00:03:02.8838054 delay: 5
NextRetryDelay count: 8 elapsed: 00:03:29.0223075 delay: 5
NextRetryDelay count: 9 elapsed: 00:03:55.1337186 delay: 5
NextRetryDelay count: 10 elapsed: 00:04:21.2564770 delay: 5
```

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to look closer here. I broke the connection by shutting down the server, so I can imagine the longer 8 seconds are due to the client waiting on a timeout. But the later retries should be instantaneous as there is nothing listening on the target. I'll have to try this in other situation as well with different ways of breaking the connection.